# I fished up an OP bow and I want to know the chances

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was fishing during rain fall in Minecraft with a "Luck of the Sea 3" and "Lure 3" fishing rod and I fished up a bow with these enchantments:

- Unbreaking 3
- Flame Aspect 1
- Power 4
- Punch 2
- Mending 1

This was in Minecraft 1.20.2 on normal difficulty. I'm quite interested to know what the probability of such a good bow being fished up.

Comment: This is tricky, I can't find real data on this, we only know that the base enchantability of a bow is 1 and that the chance of fishing a bow with LotS3 is 1.9%. We can't use my answer to your previous question because it requires the number of bookshelves.

Comment: The part we can maybe save is "with probability `(modified level + 1) / 50`, keep going. Otherwise, stop picking bonus enchantments." It's hard to find an enchanted bow, but each time you fish one it has several enchantments on it. You also need a bit of luck to avoid the curse enchantments :)